# How to get complex data from data folder in Hugo

Tags: hugo, go-templates

Having the following file in the data folder:

```
# data/files.json
{
  "test/file1.txt": "abcd/1234567890.txt",
  "test/file2.txt": "bcde/1234567890.txt"
}
```

How do I obtain the value of "`test/file1.txt`" from the map? For example from this file

```
// layout/index.ace
= doctype html
html lang={{ .Site.Language.Lang }}
body
  p {{ .Site.Data.files.????? }}
```

This is my environment:

```
$ go version
  go version go1.9.2 linux/amd64
$ hugo version
  Hugo Static Site Generator v0.35-DEV linux/amd64 BuildDate:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// layout/index.ace
= doctype html
html lang={{ .Site.Language.Lang }}
body
  p {{ index .Site.Data.files "test/file1.txt" }}
```

does the trick.